# How to fix css/html for content when screen in transition from full to smaller screen?

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have an issue with my css and HTML when it comes to page resize.

Now currently it works perfectly when it's full screen (laptop computer or full screen mobile). What happens is the two questions appear side by side in full screen and in mobile it's one after another.

The only issue I have is that in between stage. If you look at the image provided, you can see it looks incorrect. What I would be hoping is the second question go benath the first question whilst I transition from full to mobile screen, like I said this doesn't happen till the width of the screen is much smaller.

My question is simply how to correct this?

[image]

```css
.quesalignleft {
  float: left;
}

.quesalignright {
  float: right;
}

.wrap,
header nav,
footer nav {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
}

@media (min-width: 1024px) {
  .wrap,
  header nav,
  footer nav {
    width: 95%;
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="slideInRight" id="slide=59">
  <div class="wrap">
    <h4 style="text-align: center; padding-bottom: 1em;">Lesson 5: Intro Into Automation - Practice Questions 1</h4>
    <div class="quesalignleft size-45">
      <p><strong>1: Which of the following is Gherkin syntax is correct?
                  </strong></p>
      <ol class="answerslist">
        <li>Given… When… And… Then…</li>
        <li>Given… When… Then… Then…</li>
        <li>When… Then… Given… When… Then…</li>
        <li>When… And… When… Then… And…</li>
      </ol>
    </div>
    <div class="quesalignright size-45 secondquestion">
      <p><strong>2: The code that performs all the interactions are stored within where in Page Object Model?</strong></p>
      <ol class="answerslist">
        <li>Features</li>
        <li>Steps</li>
        <li>Methods</li>
        <li>Elements</li>
      </ol>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is your usage of `float`, your `.quesalignright` is doing exactly what you are telling it, it is **floating on the right**, which means it is positionning itself on the `.wrap` right side and, if there is not enough space on the x-axis, going under other floating contents (your 1st question in this case).

May I suggest : use `float: left` on all questions and use `max-width: 50%` on large screens so that your questions appear next to eachother if you want to.

```css
.quesalignleft {
  float: left;
}

.wrap,
header nav,
footer nav {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
}

@media (min-width: 1024px) {
  .wrap,
  header nav,
  footer nav {
    width: 95%;
  }
  
  .quesalignleft {
    max-width: 50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="slideInRight" id="slide=59">
  <div class="wrap">
    <h4 style="text-align: center; padding-bottom: 1em;">Lesson 5: Intro Into Automation - Practice Questions 1</h4>
    <div class="quesalignleft size-45">
      <p><strong>1: Which of the following is Gherkin syntax is correct?
                  </strong></p>
      <ol class="answerslist">
        <li>Given… When… And… Then…</li>
        <li>Given… When… Then… Then…</li>
        <li>When… Then… Given… When… Then…</li>
        <li>When… And… When… Then… And…</li>
      </ol>
    </div>
    <div class="quesalignleft size-45 secondquestion">
      <p><strong>2: The code that performs all the interactions are stored within where in Page Object Model?</strong></p>
      <ol class="answerslist">
        <li>Features</li>
        <li>Steps</li>
        <li>Methods</li>
        <li>Elements</li>
      </ol>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `float` with media query (you code)

```css
.quesalignleft {
  float: left;
}

.quesalignright {
  float: right;
}

.wrap,
header nav,
footer nav {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
 .quesalignright {
  float: left;
}
}
```

```html
<section class="slideInRight" id="slide=59">
  <div class="wrap">
    <h4 style="text-align: center; padding-bottom: 1em;">Lesson 5: Intro Into Automation - Practice Questions 1</h4>
    <div class="quesalignleft size-45">
      <p><strong>1: Which of the following is Gherkin syntax is correct?
                  </strong></p>
      <ol class="answerslist">
        <li>Given… When… And… Then…</li>
        <li>Given… When… Then… Then…</li>
        <li>When… Then… Given… When… Then…</li>
        <li>When… And… When… Then… And…</li>
      </ol>
    </div>
    <div class="quesalignright size-45 secondquestion">
      <p><strong>2: The code that performs all the interactions are stored within where in Page Object Model?</strong></p>
      <ol class="answerslist">
        <li>Features</li>
        <li>Steps</li>
        <li>Methods</li>
        <li>Elements</li>
      </ol>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Using `flex` with media query

```css
.quesalignleft {
  width: 100%;
}

.quesalignright {
  width: 100%;
}
.box {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
.box {
    display: block;
}
}
.wrap,
header nav,
footer nav {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
}

@media (min-width: 1024px) {
  .wrap,
  header nav,
  footer nav {
    width: 95%;
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="slideInRight" id="slide=59">
  <div class="wrap">
    <h4 style="text-align: center; padding-bottom: 1em;">Lesson 5: Intro Into Automation - Practice Questions 1</h4>
    <div class="box">
    <div class="quesalignleft size-45">
      <p><strong>1: Which of the following is Gherkin syntax is correct?
                  </strong></p>
      <ol class="answerslist">
        <li>Given… When… And… Then…</li>
        <li>Given… When… Then… Then…</li>
        <li>When… Then… Given… When… Then…</li>
        <li>When… And… When… Then… And…</li>
      </ol>
    </div>
    <div class="quesalignright size-45 secondquestion">
      <p><strong>2: The code that performs all the interactions are stored within where in Page Object Model?</strong></p>
      <ol class="answerslist">
        <li>Features</li>
        <li>Steps</li>
        <li>Methods</li>
        <li>Elements</li>
      </ol>
    </div>
  </div></div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@media (max-width: 1024px) {
    .wrap,
    header nav,
    footer nav {
        width: 95%;
    }
    .quesalignright {
        float: left;
    }
}
```

Change the following code
in place of min-width: you have to write max-width
and the float : left code as shown above